# Appropriate repositories for gcc-4.3 (Older versoin)

Tags: gcc

How can I determine the correct repositories for gcc-4.3.
In another thread I got the following information.

---

For  gcc-3.4

Since this version is available in the older releases of Ubuntu, we need to have the appropriate repositories for the version. From some search, I found them to be the following, which have to be added to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb     http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070730T000000Z/ lenny main
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20070730T000000Z/ lenny main
deb     http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20070730T000000Z/ lenny/updates main
deb-src http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20070730T000000Z/ lenny/updates main
```

---

But How can I find the same for gcc-4.3?

Comment: As far as a package install of gcc-4.3 on any supported release of Ubuntu I believe you're wasting your time. libgcc1 will break on any version of gcc-4.3 other than gcc-4.3.6-1 which doesn't exist as a package, never has, never will.